# PHP transformed image?

Tags: image-transforms, php, image, bootstrap-craft

I’m using Craft to add CMS functionality to an e-commerce website via `craft/app/bootstrap.php`

Trying to pull a 'timeline' structure with a `featuredImage` Asset Field.

This code works and pulls the full size image, but I can’t work out how to pull the ‘small’ size of image which is set up as a transform.

I assume it should be something like `$entry->featuredImage[0]->url['small']` but nothing seems to be working.

Any help appreciated.

```
$timeline = Craft\craft()->elements->getCriteria(Craft\ElementType::Entry);
$timeline->section = 'timeline';
$timeline->with = 'featuredImage';
$timeline->withTransforms = 'small';

foreach ($timeline as $entry)
{                       
  ?>
      <li>
          <div class="imgholder"><img src="<?php echo $entry->featuredImage[0]->url; ?>" alt="<?php echo $entry->featuredImage[0]->title; ?>"/></div>
          <h4><?php echo $entry->title; ?></h4>
          <?php echo $entry->body; ?>
       </li>
  <?php
}
```

Comment: Completely untested so adding as a comment, but try: `echo $entry->featuredImage[0]->getUrl('small');`

Answer (score 3):

`$entry->featuredImage[0]->getUrl('small');` works.